# Contact Summary Layout Extension - Screen display problem

Tags: extension, contact-layout-editor

I have tried to install the Contact Layout extension and get the following issue shown in the attached screen shot. I am using

- Drupal 7.72
- CiviCRM 5.24.3
- Contact Summary Layout 1.7.1
- Angular Profiles 4.6-1.0.2

I wonder if someone might point me in the right direction to get this resolved.

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser javascript console since it looks like something javascript-y isn't loading.

Comment: maybe disable a few other extensions in case any are running interference eg civimobile

Comment: Are you able to update to a later civi? I'm conscious there are security patches missing on 5.24 & I think this change to CLE might break compatibility with older civi versions

https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout/releases/tag/1.6

Answer (score 2):

I was setting this up in a staging environment which is not up to date with the latest versions of CiviCRM. If you go are running a version of CiviCRM earlier than 5.24 then you need to apply this patch which solves the problem. The issue is not seen in versions of CiviCRM 5.25 and later.
(https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout/pull/79.diff)